# Linux CROND resource limits

Tags: linux, bash, cron, multiprocessing, limit

I have a machine with minified single user OS based on **64bit Fedora 24**:

- Vendor: Acer Veriton VN4640G
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6400T CPU @ 2.20GHz
- RAM: 4GB DDR4 2133 MHz
- Storage: 32GB 2,5" ADATA SP600

I wrote a simple script `/root/test.sh` which run 10000 processes on background:

```
ulimit -a > /tmp/ulimit
i=1
while [ $i -le 10000 ]; do
    echo $i
    sleep 60 & disown
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done
```

When I run this script directly from console, it runs 10000 sleep processes and print numbers as expected.

```
# bash test.sh
1
2
...
9999
10000

# ps ax | grep -c [s]leep
10000
```

Ulimit looks well

```
# cat /tmp/ulimit
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15339
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15339
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

## BUT

if I run this script via cron (`/etc/cron.d/custom`), e.g.

```
0  8  *  *  *    root    bash /root/test.sh
```

I see in `journalctl -e -o cat` messages like:

```
(root) CMDOUT (494)
(root) CMDOUT (495)
(root) CMDOUT (496)
(root) CMDOUT (/root/test.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable)
(root) CMDOUT (/root/test.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable)
(root) CMDOUT (/root/test.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable)
(root) CMDOUT (/root/test.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable)
(root) CMDOUT (/root/proc.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

So it run only about 500 processes and then cann't fork any other process even if there is still enough resources and user limits are the same as console case.

```
# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3,8G        472M        2,8G         62M        498M        3,0G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

The count of running sleeps is always the same. **Is there any recource limit for tasks run from cron?**

P.S.: I did the test even on full Fedora 24 and result is the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution during writing this question.

The main pointer to the problem was that I once saw in `journalctl` message

```
kernel: cgroup: fork rejected by pids controller in /system.slice/crond.service
```

So I checked the `cron.service` and found a parameter **TasksMax**.

```
# systemctl show crond.service
Type=simple
Restart=no
...
TasksMax=512
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/crond (ignore_errors=no)
UMask=0022
LimitCPU=18446744073709551615
LimitCPUSoft=18446744073709551615
```

## Solution

Add parameter **TasksMax** to the service configuration in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service`, e.g.:

*Note*: As Mark Plotnick wrote, better way is copy this service to `/etc/systemd/system/` folder and modify this file to avoid rewriting service in `/usr/` during upgrade.

```
# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service
[Unit]
Description=Command Scheduler
After=auditd.service nss-user-lookup.target systemd-user-sessions.service time-sync.target ypbind.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/crond
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/crond -n $CRONDARGS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
TasksMax=100000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then reload systemd daemons

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

### General solution

If you want avoid this problem with any systemd service you can change default value in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, e.g.:

```
sed -i 's/#DefaultTasksMax=512/DefaultTasksMax=10000/' /etc/systemd/system.conf
```

And reload systemd daemons to apply the changes

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

But I don't know the exact consequences of this solution, so I can not recommend it.