# Some programs not started by bash script when script ran as a crontab job but all programs can be started by manually run the bash script

Tags: linux, bash

**Problem**

I have some similar bash scripts to start about hundred processes, these bash scripts runs once very day at 09:12, they run well when the processes was not so many before, but as processes to start by scripts increased recent days, I found that some of processes not be started. I ran the script manually to check what happened, but all processes started well by the bash script be manually ran.

Some of those processes not been started leave core dump, it shows Program terminated with signal SIGABRT when call std::thread to create a thread.

The system is ubuntu server 18.04.4 LTS, crontab and manually ran as a normal user.

**What I’ve tried**

I seperated the script into two, starts diffrent part of processes each, one crontab at 09:12 the other one at 09:25. but no lucky, the first script can't start part of processes, the second can start none of processes.

I have checked if something reached system limits, no limits reached.

**Code**

bash script "Signal_IF_trend.sh" as below

```
#!/bin/bash
## argument not given
if [ $# -eq 0 ];
then
        echo "argument：start - to start all processes， stop - to stop all processes"
        exit 0
fi

arr_IFtrend=(
    "2927" "2932" "2935" "2936" "2937" "2938" "3125" "3127" "3128" "3129" "3130" "3329" "3330" "3331"
    "3332" "3333" "3334" "3725" "3726" "3727" "3728" "3729" "3925" "3927" "3928" "3929" "3930" "4124"
    "4125" "4126" "4127" "4128" "4320" "4321" "4322" "4323" "4521" "4522" "4523" "4524" "4525" "4718"
    "4719" "4720" "4721" "4729" "5117" "5121" "5122" "5123" "5317" "5318" "5319" "5322" "5323" "5518"
    "5519" "5523" "5524" "5916" "5917" "5918" "5919" "6112" "6117" "6126" "6317" "6321" "6322" "6323"
    "6324" "6712" "6717" "6718" "6719" "6720" "6721" "7111" "7112" "7113" "7114" "7115" "7116" "7312"
    "7313" "7314" "7315" "7316" "7611" "7612" "7613" "7614" "7615" "7616" "7914" "7915" "7916" "7917"
    "8113" "8114" "8115" "8116" "8117" "8118" "8119"
)
ver_trend="v064"

ulimit -c unlimited

BASEPATH=$(cd `dirname $0`;pwd)

case "$1" in

    start)
    count=0
        for var in ${arr_IFtrend[@]}
        do
                count=$(($count+1))
                if(($count % 10 == 0))
                then
                        /bin/sleep 5
                fi
                cd $BASEPATH/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF$var
                nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var >/dev/null 2>&1 &
                echo $! > run.pid
                echo "Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF$var/IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var started"
        done
        ;;


    stop)
        for var in ${arr_IFtrend[@]}
        do
                cd $BASEPATH/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF$var
                kill `cat run.pid`
                rm -rf run.pid
                echo "Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF$var/IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var stoping..."
        done
        ;;

    zip)
        for var in ${arr_IFtrend[@]}
        do
                cd $BASEPATH/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF$var
                gzip *.log
                find . -mtime +7 -name "*.gz" -exec rm -rf {} \;
        done
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

the users crontab

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command

# IC IF T ##########################
# ----------------------------------
# start processes
0 9     * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IC.sh start > /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IC_crontab.log
5 9     * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_deviation.sh start > /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_devication_crontab.log
10 9    * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_KNATR.sh start > /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_KNATR_crontab.log
12 9    * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh start > /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend_crontab.log
# 16 9    * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_NTime.sh start > /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_NTime_crontab.log
25 9    * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_option.sh start > /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_option_crontab.log
# stop processes
30 15   * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IC.sh stop
33 15   * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_deviation.sh stop
33 15   * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_KNATR.sh stop
# 35 15 * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_NTime.sh stop
36 15   * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh stop
39 15   * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_option.sh stop
# zip logs
30 16   * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IC.sh zip
35 16   * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_deviation.sh zip
37 16   * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_KNATR.sh zip
# 40 16   * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_NTime.sh zip
45 16   * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh zip
50 16   * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_Comodity.sh zip
55 16   * * 1-5 /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_option.sh zip
```

gdb displays for the core dump(updated after install glibc source)

```
faund@Sirius:~/debug$ gdb IFtrend_NTickDel00_v064_8118 core 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from IFtrend_NTickDel00_v064_8118...done.

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 25832]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./IFtrend_NTickDel00_v064_8118'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) info source
Current source file is ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c
Compilation directory is /build/glibc-2ORdQG/glibc-2.27/signal
Source language is c.
Producer is GNU C11 7.5.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -O2 -O3 -std=gnu11 -fgnu89-inline -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -fstack-protector-strong -fPIC -ftls-model=initial-exec -fstack-protector-strong.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Does not include preprocessor macro info.
(gdb) set substitute-path /build/glibc-2ORdQG/glibc-2.27 /opt/src/glibc-2.27
(gdb) frame 0
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  }
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007f9aac6d08b1 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007f9aad0c3957 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007f9aad0c9ae6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007f9aad0c9b21 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007f9aad0c9d54 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007f9aad0c5a23 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007f9aad0f49a9 in std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x0000559c6fcc5319 in std::thread::thread<void (MfLogger::*)(), MfLogger*> (__f=<optimized out>, this=0x7ffc745ecc80) at /usr/include/c++/7/thread:126
#9  MfLogger::MfLogger (this=0x7ffc745ed670, logFileName=...) at /home/siko/Documents/V64/IF_Drange_trend/SharedDataStructs/MfLogger.cpp:13
#10 0x0000559c6fcc36cb in main () at /home/siko/Documents/V64/IF_Drange_trend/Strategy/main.cpp:59
(gdb)
```

user received mail

```
Subject: Cron <xxsc@Strategy2> /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh start > /home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend_crontab.log
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/xxsc>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=xxsc>
Message-Id: <20200902011301.AA2C0B0040A@Strategy2>
Date: Wed,  2 Sep 2020 09:13:01 +0800 (CST)

/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10014 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF6324)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10015 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF6712)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10016 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF6717)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10017 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF6718)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10019 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF6720)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10022 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10069 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7113)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10070 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7114)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10071 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7115)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10072 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7116)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10073 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7312)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10074 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7313)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10075 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7314)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10076 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7315)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10077 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7316)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10078 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10104 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7612)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10105 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7613)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10106 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7614)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10107 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7615)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10108 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7616)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10109 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7914)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10110 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7915)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10111 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7916)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10112 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1  (wd: ~/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF/IFtrend_NTick_Del00/IF7917)
/home/xxsc/ProductionEnv/Signal_IF_trend.sh: line 30: 10113 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup ./IFtrend_NTickDel00_${ver_trend}_$var > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: 51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory. seems to be your problem. i found a answer related to raise.c here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48287761/1462096

Comment: @b10n1k I have done the steps said in the post you refered, and update the gdb outputs in my post. Seems only show more details for the crash point.

Comment: I found a post have the same situation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534976/linux-crond-resource-limits

Comment: I think I have figure out the problem, as I followed https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168797/multiple-processes-getting-stopped-with-error-resource-temporarily-unavailable typed the command **systemctl status cron**, I saw the output `Tasks: 4740 (limit: 4915)`. for those processes started by the first script manually were not count in, so that the second script can start all the processes.

Comment: **systemctl show -p TasksMax xxsc** shows `TasksMax=4915` . I believe that find the way to change the TasksMax setting will get this problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this problem solved.
The key is TasksMax's setting for cron.service limits the scripts to create more processes.

**Resolution for Ubuntu Server 18.04**

Edit the system.conf file in /etc/systemd

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system.conf
```

add the following line to the end of system.conf

```
DefaultTasksMax=100000
```

reboot the server

**How to check**

command "systemctl status cron" can show below infomation

before modify system.conf

```
xxsc@Strategy2:/etc/systemd$ sudo systemctl service cron
Unknown operation service.
xxsc@Strategy2:/etc/systemd$ sudo systemctl status cron
¡ñ cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-08-29 15:26:17 CST; 3 days ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 966 (cron)
    Tasks: 4743 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           ©À©€  966 /usr/sbin/cron -f
           ©À©€ 4322 ./prodTickRecorderv057.15
           ©À©€ 4355 ./Comodity_AP_NTime_Del00_v0533_0212
           ©À©€ 4356 ./Comodity_AP_NTime_Del00_v0533_0306
           ...
```

notice the line Tasks: 4743 (limit: 4915), Tasks is close to limit.
after modify the system.conf file

```
xxsc@Strategy2:~$ systemctl status cron
¡ñ cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-09-02 15:47:46 CST; 2min 26s ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 1069 (cron)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 100000)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           ©ž©€1069 /usr/sbin/cron -f
           ...
```